# Cannot create value: Error writing to the registry

Tags: windows-registry

So I get this error when trying to add a dword or even change a value in a key under hklm\system\CurrentControlSet\services\x1

When I look at the effective permissions, I have full control and I am the owner of the key. If I check the next key under "services," I can edit the values and add values under it. But, for some reason, I can't edit this key for the particular software on a couple of machines.

I have tried running as administrator but that doesn't work either.

So if I have full control and I'm the owner, is there something else that could be locking this key? The permissions are identical with the next key in hklm\system\CurrentControlSet\services so I'm not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Anti-virus packages actively disallow editing of their own and often some system services.  Try editing the key in Safe Mode, and/or with AV disabled/uninstalled.

Comment: Holy crud. That worked. I booted into safe mode and could change the value. Thanks a ton, techie007.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked, I'll throw it in as an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some programs (Anti-malware packages for example) actively disallow editing of their own, and often some system, services.

Try editing the key while in Safe Mode, and/or with any running Anti-malware disabled/uninstalled.

Comment: How do they do it? Is the antivirus running in a higher level that the permission checking system? How do they capture these actions and prevent them? I was having the same issue with specific keys